# Hebrew in strings ruby not showing the hebrew correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hebrew

I got this model call pile that inherits from activerecord::base

in it there is a method

```
  def self.default_piles(type)
    piles = []
    if type == :rsq
      piles << {:name_en_us => "Extremely Uncharacteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Extrem uncharakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "极不符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "全くあてはまらない",
                :name_es_es => "Extremamente poco característico",
                :name_it_it => "Estremamente non caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "للغاية",
                :name_et_ee => "Äärmiselt mitteiseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Ekstremt ukarakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Extreem weinig typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Vôbec neplatí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Výrazně netypické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Полностью не характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "전혀 특징적이 아님",
                :name_pl_pl => "Wyjątkowo Nietrafne",
                :name_he_il => "לא מאפיין כלל",
                :name_fr_fr => "Extrêmement Non Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 3}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Quite Uncharacteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Sehr uncharakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "很不符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "あてはまらない",
                :name_es_es => "Muy poco característico",
                :name_it_it => "Molto non caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "غير مميّز تماماً",
                :name_et_ee => "Täiesti mitteiseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Meget ukarakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Heel weinig typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Veľmi neplatí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Značně netypické",
                :name_ru_ru => "В общем не характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "그런 특징이 거의 없음",
                :name_pl_pl => "Nietrafne",
                :name_he_il => "לא מאפיין למדי",
                :name_fr_fr => "Non Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 6}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Fairly Uncharacteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Ziemlich uncharakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "较不符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "ほぼあてはまらない",
                :name_es_es => "Bastante poco característico",
                :name_it_it => "Piuttosto non caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "غير مميّز باعتدال",
                :name_et_ee => "Üsna mitteiseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Temmelig ukarakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Redelijk weinig typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Dosť neplatí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Docela netypické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Отчасти не характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "그런 특징이 별로 없음",
                :name_pl_pl => "Raczej Nietrafne",
                :name_he_il => "לא כל כך מאפיין",
                :name_fr_fr => "Plutôt Non Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 11}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Somewhat Uncharacteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Ein wenig uncharakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "稍不符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "ややあてはまらない",
                :name_es_es => "Poco característico",
                :name_it_it => "Leggermente non caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "غير مميّز إلى حد ما",
                :name_et_ee => "Mõnevõrra mitteiseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Lidt ukarakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Ietwat weinig typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Trochu neplatí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Trochu netypické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Скорее не характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "그런 특징이 다소 없는 편임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Trochę Nietrafne",
                :name_he_il => "לא מאפיין במידה מסוימת",
                :name_fr_fr => "Modérément Non Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 15}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Relatively Neutral",
                :name_de_de => "Relativ neutral",
                :name_zh_cn => "相对中立",
                :name_ja_jp => "どちらでもない",
                :name_es_es => "Relativamente neutral",
                :name_it_it => "Relativamente neutrale",
                :name_ar_iq => "محايد نسبياً",
                :name_et_ee => "Võrdlemisi neutraalne",
                :name_da_dk => "Relativt neutral",
                :name_nl_nl => "Relatief neutraal",
                :name_sk_sk => "Pomerne neutrálne",
                :name_cs_cz => "Poměrně neutrální",
                :name_ru_ru => "Относительно нейтрально",
                :name_ko_kr => "비교적 중립임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Stosunkowo Neutralne",
                :name_he_il => "ניטראלי באופן יחסי",
                :name_fr_fr => "Relativement Neutre",
                :capacity => 19}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Somewhat Characteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Ein wenig charakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "稍符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "ややあてはまる",
                :name_es_es => "Algo característico",
                :name_it_it => "Leggermente caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "مميّز إلى حد ما",
                :name_et_ee => "Mõnevõrra iseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Lidt karakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Ietwat typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Trochu platí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Trochu typické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Скорее характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "약간 특징적임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Trochę Trafne",
                :name_he_il => "מאפיין במידה מסוימת",
                :name_fr_fr => "Modérément Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 15}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Fairly Characteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Ziemlich charakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "较为符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "ほぼあてはまる",
                :name_es_es => "Bastante característico",
                :name_it_it => "Piuttosto caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "مميّز باعتدال",
                :name_et_ee => "Üsna iseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Temmelig karakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Redelijk typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Dosť platí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Docela typické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Отчасти характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "꽤 특징적임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Raczej Trafne",
                :name_he_il => "קצת מאפיין",
                :name_fr_fr => "Plutôt Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 11}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Quite Characteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Sehr charakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "很符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "よくあてはまる",
                :name_es_es => "Muy característico",
                :name_it_it => "Molto caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "مميّز تماماً",
                :name_et_ee => "Täiesti iseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Meget karakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Heel typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Veľmi platí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Značně typické",
                :name_ru_ru => "В общем характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "상당히 특징적임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Trafne",
                :name_he_il => "די מאפיין",
                :name_fr_fr => "Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 6}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Extremely Characteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Extrem charakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "极符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "すごくよくあてはまる",
                :name_es_es => "Extremamente característico",
                :name_it_it => "Estremamente caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "مميّز للغاية",
                :name_et_ee => "Äärmiselt iseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Ekstremt karakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Extreem typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Úplne platí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Výrazně typické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Полностью характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "매우 특징적임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Wyjątkowo Trafne",
                :name_he_il => "מאפיין מאד",
                :name_fr_fr => "Extrêmement Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 3}

    elsif type == :rbq
      piles << {:name_en_us => "Extremely Uncharacteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Extrem uncharakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "极不符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "全くあてはまらない",
                :name_es_es => "Extremamente poco característico",
                :name_it_it => "Estremamente non caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "للغاية",
                :name_et_ee => "Äärmiselt mitteiseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Ekstremt ukarakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Extreem weinig typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Vôbec neplatí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Výrazně netypické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Полностью не характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "전혀 특징적이 아님",
                :name_pl_pl => "Wyjątkowo Nietrafne",
                :name_he_il => "לא מאפיין כלל",
                :name_fr_fr => "Extrêmement Non Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 3}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Quite Uncharacteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Sehr uncharakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "很不符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "あてはまらない",
                :name_es_es => "Muy poco característico",
                :name_it_it => "Molto non caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "غير مميّز تماماً",
                :name_et_ee => "Täiesti mitteiseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Meget ukarakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Heel weinig typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Veľmi neplatí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Značně netypické",
                :name_ru_ru => "В общем не характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "그런 특징이 거의 없음",
                :name_pl_pl => "Nietrafne",
                :name_he_il => "לא מאפיין למדי",
                :name_fr_fr => "Non Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 5}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Fairly Uncharacteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Ziemlich uncharakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "较不符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "ほぼあてはまらない",
                :name_es_es => "Bastante poco característico",
                :name_it_it => "Piuttosto non caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "غير مميّز باعتدال",
                :name_et_ee => "Üsna mitteiseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Temmelig ukarakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Redelijk weinig typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Dosť neplatí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Docela netypické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Отчасти не характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "그런 특징이 별로 없음",
                :name_pl_pl => "Raczej Nietrafne",
                :name_he_il => "לא כל כך מאפיין",
                :name_fr_fr => "Plutôt Non Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 7}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Somewhat Uncharacteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Ein wenig uncharakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "稍不符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "ややあてはまらない",
                :name_es_es => "Poco característico",
                :name_it_it => "Leggermente non caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "غير مميّز إلى حد ما",
                :name_et_ee => "Mõnevõrra mitteiseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Lidt ukarakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Ietwat weinig typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Trochu neplatí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Trochu netypické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Скорее не характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "그런 특징이 다소 없는 편임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Trochę Nietrafne",
                :name_he_il => "לא מאפיין במידה מסוימת",
                :name_fr_fr => "Modérément Non Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 11}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Relatively Neutral",
                :name_de_de => "Relativ neutral",
                :name_zh_cn => "相对中立",
                :name_ja_jp => "どちらでもない",
                :name_es_es => "Relativamente neutral",
                :name_it_it => "Relativamente neutrale",
                :name_ar_iq => "محايد نسبياً",
                :name_et_ee => "Võrdlemisi neutraalne",
                :name_da_dk => "Relativt neutral",
                :name_nl_nl => "Relatief neutraal",
                :name_sk_sk => "Pomerne neutrálne",
                :name_cs_cz => "Poměrně neutrální",
                :name_ru_ru => "Относительно нейтрально",
                :name_ko_kr => "비교적 중립임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Stosunkowo Neutralne",
                :name_he_il => "ניטראלי באופן יחסי",
                :name_fr_fr => "Relativement Neutre",
                :capacity => 16}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Somewhat Characteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Ein wenig charakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "稍符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "ややあてはまる",
                :name_es_es => "Algo característico",
                :name_it_it => "Leggermente caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "مميّز إلى حد ما",
                :name_et_ee => "Mõnevõrra iseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Lidt karakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Ietwat typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Trochu platí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Trochu typické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Скорее характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "약간 특징적임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Trochę Trafne",
                :name_he_il => "מאפיין במידה מסוימת",
                :name_fr_fr => "Modérément Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 11}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Fairly Characteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Ziemlich charakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "较为符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "ほぼあてはまる",
                :name_es_es => "Bastante característico",
                :name_it_it => "Piuttosto caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "مميّز باعتدال",
                :name_et_ee => "Üsna iseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Temmelig karakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Redelijk typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Dosť platí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Docela typické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Отчасти характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "꽤 특징적임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Raczej Trafne",
                :name_he_il => "קצת מאפיין",
                :name_fr_fr => "Plutôt Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 7}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Quite Characteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Sehr charakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "很符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "よくあてはまる",
                :name_es_es => "Muy característico",
                :name_it_it => "Molto caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "مميّز تماماً",
                :name_et_ee => "Täiesti iseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Meget karakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Heel typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Veľmi platí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Značně typické",
                :name_ru_ru => "В общем характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "상당히 특징적임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Trafne",
                :name_he_il => "די מאפיין",
                :name_fr_fr => "Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 5}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Extremely Characteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Extrem charakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "极符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "すごくよくあてはまる",
                :name_es_es => "Extremamente característico",
                :name_it_it => "Estremamente caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "مميّز للغاية",
                :name_et_ee => "Äärmiselt iseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Ekstremt karakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Extreem typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Úplne platí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Výrazně typické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Полностью характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "매우 특징적임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Wyjątkowo Trafne",
                :name_he_il => "מאפיין מאד",
                :name_fr_fr => "Extrêmement Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 3}

    elsif type == :caq
      piles << {:name_en_us => "Extremely Uncharacteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Extrem uncharakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "极不符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "全くあてはまらない",
                :name_es_es => "Extremamente poco característico",
                :name_it_it => "Estremamente non caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "للغاية",
                :name_et_ee => "Äärmiselt mitteiseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Ekstremt ukarakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Extreem weinig typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Vôbec neplatí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Výrazně netypické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Полностью не характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "전혀 특징적이 아님",
                :name_pl_pl => "Wyjątkowo Nietrafne",
                :name_he_il => "לא מאפיין כלל",
                :name_fr_fr => "Extrêmement Non Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 5}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Quite Uncharacteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Sehr uncharakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "很不符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "あてはまらない",
                :name_es_es => "Muy poco característico",
                :name_it_it => "Molto non caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "غير مميّز تماماً",
                :name_et_ee => "Täiesti mitteiseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Meget ukarakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Heel weinig typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Veľmi neplatí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Značně netypické",
                :name_ru_ru => "В общем не характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "그런 특징이 거의 없음",
                :name_pl_pl => "Nietrafne",
                :name_he_il => "לא מאפיין למדי",
                :name_fr_fr => "Non Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 8}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Fairly Uncharacteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Ziemlich uncharakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "较不符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "ほぼあてはまらない",
                :name_es_es => "Bastante poco característico",
                :name_it_it => "Piuttosto non caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "غير مميّز باعتدال",
                :name_et_ee => "Üsna mitteiseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Temmelig ukarakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Redelijk weinig typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Dosť neplatí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Docela netypické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Отчасти не характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "그런 특징이 별로 없음",
                :name_pl_pl => "Raczej Nietrafne",
                :name_he_il => "לא כל כך מאפיין",
                :name_fr_fr => "Plutôt Non Caractéristique",
                :capacity => 12}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Somewhat Uncharacteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Ein wenig uncharakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "稍不符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "ややあてはまらない",
                :name_es_es => "Poco característico",
                :name_it_it => "Leggermente non caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "غير مميّز إلى حد ما",
                :name_et_ee => "Mõnevõrra mitteiseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Lidt ukarakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Ietwat weinig typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Trochu neplatí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Trochu netypické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Скорее не характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "그런 특징이 다소 없는 편임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Trochę Nietrafne",
                :name_fr_fr => "Modérément Non Caractéristique",
                :name_he_il => "לא מאפיין במידה מסוימת",
                :capacity => 16}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Relatively Neutral",
                :name_de_de => "Relativ neutral",
                :name_zh_cn => "相对中立",
                :name_ja_jp => "どちらでもない",
                :name_es_es => "Relativamente neutral",
                :name_it_it => "Relativamente neutrale",
                :name_ar_iq => "محايد نسبياً",
                :name_et_ee => "Võrdlemisi neutraalne",
                :name_da_dk => "Relativt neutral",
                :name_nl_nl => "Relatief neutraal",
                :name_sk_sk => "Pomerne neutrálne",
                :name_cs_cz => "Poměrně neutrální",
                :name_ru_ru => "Относительно нейтрально",
                :name_ko_kr => "비교적 중립임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Stosunkowo Neutralne",
                :name_fr_fr => "Relativement Neutre",
                :name_he_il => "ניטראלי באופן יחסי",
                :capacity => 18}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Somewhat Characteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Ein wenig charakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "稍符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "ややあてはまる",
                :name_es_es => "Algo característico",
                :name_it_it => "Leggermente caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "مميّز إلى حد ما",
                :name_et_ee => "Mõnevõrra iseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Lidt karakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Ietwat typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Trochu platí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Trochu typické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Скорее характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "약간 특징적임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Trochę Trafne",
                :name_fr_fr => "Modérément Caractéristique",
                :name_he_il => "מאפיין במידה מסוימת",
                :capacity => 16}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Fairly Characteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Ziemlich charakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "较为符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "ほぼあてはまる",
                :name_es_es => "Bastante característico",
                :name_it_it => "Piuttosto caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "مميّز باعتدال",
                :name_et_ee => "Üsna iseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Temmelig karakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Redelijk typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Dosť platí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Docela typické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Отчасти характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "꽤 특징적임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Raczej Trafne",
                :name_fr_fr => "Plutôt Caractéristique",
                :name_he_il => "קצת מאפיין",
                :capacity => 12}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Quite Characteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Sehr charakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "很符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "よくあてはまる",
                :name_es_es => "Muy característico",
                :name_it_it => "Molto caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "مميّز تماماً",
                :name_et_ee => "Täiesti iseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Meget karakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Heel typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Veľmi platí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Značně typické",
                :name_ru_ru => "В общем характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "상당히 특징적임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Trafne",
                :name_fr_fr => "Caractéristique",
                :name_he_il => "די מאפיין",
                :capacity => 8}

      piles << {:name_en_us => "Extremely Characteristic",
                :name_de_de => "Extrem charakteristisch",
                :name_zh_cn => "极符合情况的",
                :name_ja_jp => "すごくよくあてはまる",
                :name_es_es => "Extremamente característico",
                :name_it_it => "Estremamente caratteristico",
                :name_ar_iq => "مميّز للغاية",
                :name_et_ee => "Äärmiselt iseloomulik",
                :name_da_dk => "Ekstremt karakteristisk",
                :name_nl_nl => "Extreem typerend",
                :name_sk_sk => "Úplne platí",
                :name_cs_cz => "Výrazně typické",
                :name_ru_ru => "Полностью характеризуется",
                :name_ko_kr => "매우 특징적임",
                :name_pl_pl => "Wyjątkowo Trafne",
                :name_fr_fr => "Extrêmement Caractéristique",
                :name_he_il => "מאפיין מאד",
                :capacity => 5}
    else
      raise ArgumentError.new "You must pass :rsq, :rbq, or :caq to this method"
    end
    piles
  end
end
```

there are nine columns in total, extremely uncharacteristic, quite uncharacteristic, fairly uncharacteristic, somewhat uncharacteristic, relatively neutral, somewhat characteristic, fairly characteristic, quite characteristic, and extremely characteristic.

The 9 columns are the same for each different type.

There are translations for each one of these in various languages. I am mostly working on hebrew for now.

I am having trouble with `name_he_il` or hebrew.

in the front end its just displaying the pile name

```
.row.piles
  - @study_phase.piles.each do |pile|
    .column.pile.span-one-ninth
      .header
        %h4.col-header.nine-pile-name= pile.name
```

if the user clicks on the hebrew locale then it will display the name_he_il's value.

I am having trouble with the hebrew wrap in the strings. It just isn't displayed correctly.

One of the column hebrew translation is cut off in the front.

this one

```
:name_he_il => "לא מאפיין למדי",
```

under quite uncharacteristic will show up in the front semi cut off. At first I thought the strings were too long and it was the width of the column that was doing it. However strings from other translations are longer and they are displayed correctly.

The strings were either cut off or just aren't showing up correctly. The 4th one somewhat uncharacteristic becomes a duplicate of the fifth one in the front. Maybe the 4th one couldn't be displayed and the app found another one to sub it. I don't understand hebrew so I am having a huge language barrier as well. I have been copying/pasting the translations into the piles and I know the file with the translations are correct. I have checked for extra spaces because I know the file is sensitive.

What should I look for to format the hebrew characters correctly in the string data structure inside a hash?

can someone take a look at the 9 translations and tell which characters are throwing that particular translation off?

Comment: is it cut off for all three or just one of them?

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate cut off for just that one. I will copy/paste the rest of the hebrew translations.

Comment: I have no experience whatsoever with displaying hebrew text, but my guess would be somehow one of the hebrew chars is a control character or something. maybe set the language of the html page to utf-8 will help

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate I added this `# encoding: UTF-8` before the pile class was defined earlier. It did not work for me. or maybe I did it incorrectly?

Comment: no that is in rails. I mean in the html page

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate in my application.html.haml file there is already this `%meta{:content => "text/html; charset=utf-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}` would you know another way?